# Laravel/PHP: my unix time stamp is not showing as less than my sistem time

Tags: php

I chose a date earlier this month (february 2) and the unix timestamp is `1612304580000` .  I am doing operator to check if that time is less than the current time using PHP's `time()`

```
//time() is 1614032830;

$oldTime = 1612304580000;
$oldTime < time() // false;
```

I am using `time()` incorrectly?

Comment: Your timestamp is incorrect. You are storing an extra 1000 places. Should be `1612304580`, for future debugging https://3v4l.org/qEbLF

Comment: `1612304580000` is a much bigger number than `1614032830`. Where do you get `1612304580000` from?

Comment: @JeroenvanderLaan I am passing it from the frontend in a time picker.  It is set as a string "2021-02-27T22:24:00.000Z" on the frontend and in JS, I convert it to `time = Date.parse("2021-02-27T22:24:00.000Z");`, which gives me the value `1612304580000`

Comment: @MargieFowle3 In PHP, try `$date = new DateTimeImmutable('2021-02-27T22:24:00.000Z');` (passing the date string you get from the frontend), and then using `$date->getTimestamp();` to get the appropriate timestamp.

Comment: @JeroenvanderLaan thanks, I get `DateTimeImmutable::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (1612304580000) at position 11 (0): Unexpected character"`

Comment: You can't pass a timestamp to `DateTimeImmutable::__construct()`, only a `string` date format (such as `'2021-02-27T22:24:00.000Z'`). Alternative solution is to do `$oldTime = $oldTime / 1000` before comparing it to `time();`.

Comment: Is `time` used in front end? You should send the ISO format (which is what the `T` and `Z` is).

Comment: thanks @JeroenvanderLaan , I went with the approach of just dividing by 1000 and that worked perfectly.  Thanks!